# SQL Server query replace for MySQL Instruction

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server, and used mysql for a while now...

```
SELECT A.acol, IF(A.acol<0,"Neg","Pos") as Column2 From Table
```

I want to do something like that on SQL Server, but there doesn't exist the IF instruction.

How do I replace that if, in a SQL Server 2008 Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.acol, 
    case when A.acol < 0 then 'Neg' else 'Pos' end as Column2 
From Table
```